# Regex not to match a set of Strings

Tags: java, regex

How to construct a regex not to contain a set of strings within.

For this example, I want to validate the Address Line 1 text box so that it wont contain any secondary address parts such 'Apt', 'Bldg','Ste','Unit' etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex can be used to verify that a string does not contain a set of words. Here is a tested Java code snippet with a commented regex which does precisely this:

```java
if (s.matches("(?sxi)" +
    "# Match string containing no 'bad' words.\n" +
    "^                # Anchor to start of string.\n" +
    "(?:              # Step through string one char at a time.\n" +
    "  (?!            # Negative lookahead to exclude words.\n" +
    "    \\b          # All bad words begin on a word boundary\n" +
    "    (?:          # List of 'bad' words NOT to be matched.\n" +
    "      Apt        # Cannot be 'Apt',\n" +
    "    | Bldg       # or 'Bldg',\n" +
    "    | Ste        # or 'Ste',\n" +
    "    | Unit       # or 'Unit'.\n" +
    "    )            # End list of words NOT to be matched.\n" +
    "    \\b          # All bad words end on a word boundary\n" +
    "  )              # Not at the beginning of bad word.\n" +
    "  .              # Ok. Safe to match this character.\n" +
    ")*               # Zero or more 'not-start-of-bad-word' chars.\n" +
    "$                # Anchor to end of string.")
    ) {
    // String has no bad words.
    System.out.print("OK: String has no bad words.\n");
} else {
    // String has bad words.
    System.out.print("ERR: String has bad words.\n");
}
```

This assumes that the words must be "whole" words and that the "bad" words should be  recognized regardless of case. Note also, (as others have correctly stated), that this is not as efficient as simply checking for the presence of bad words and then taking the logical NOT.

Comment: +1 awesome. :) I still don't get it. Especially a 'negative lookahead' (is this a lookbehind?) is confusing. Do you know a page with stepwise introduction to all this possibilities? Another question: (?sxi) at the beginning means what? I guess i:=ignore case?

Comment: @user unknown: The `(?sxi)` expression at the start sets the `single-line`, `free-spacing` and `ignorecase` modifier flags. There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!

Comment: Thanks. I'm a regular user of sed and learned the basics of regexes - Groups [a-n], [::alnum::], quantifieres (a?b+c){3,4}*, capturing groups "(ab*c?)" "$1" (\1 in sed) and start-end of string/line ^$, negation of alternatives [^m-z]. But ?: and ?! are still aliens for me. Maybe I find them between your links. :)

Comment: @user unknown: If you want to really _know_ regex (in the Neo: _"I know kung-fu!"_ sense), then the absolute best way is to sit down and read Jeffrey Friedl's classic: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Best book on Regex - ever!") This is, hands down, the most useful book I have ever read. (The [slashdot review](http://news.slashdot.org/story/06/09/13/147213/Mastering-Regular-Expressions) rated it _11 out of 10!_)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to construct a regex to match strings that *don't* contain these substrings, why not construct a regex to match strings that *do* contain one or more of them?  Then if that regex returns `true`, you know that you have an invalid string.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I would need a regex that wont match because i would need to pass it as a parameter to a JSF tag.

Comment: @greg: Ok.  You should add that fact to your question.  Also, constructing the complementary (i.e. opposite) regex is probably going to be *very tricky indeed*!  So you may need to come up with an alternative strategy.

Answer (score 0):

A more theoretical answer:

Deterministic Finite Automata have a one-to-one correspondence with regular expressions; that is, for every regular language, you can construct a DFA that will accept exactly the strings that are contained in the regular language.  And, for every regular language, you can construct a regular expression that will match only the strings that are in that language.  Thus, for any regular expression, you can construct a DFA that accepts exactly the same strings, and vice versa.

A Non-Deterministic Finite Automaton (NFA) can be turned into a Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA) by constructing a DFA state for every combination of states in the NFA.  (This is |Q|<sup>2</sup> states, which is a finite number.)

With that knowledge, we can reverse a DFA `A` and produce a DFA `A'` which accepts every string that `A` rejects, and rejects every string that `A` accepts.

This can be done by turning all of the end states into temporary start states, and the start state into an end state.  Then, we proceed to add epsilon-transitions from a new starting state to every one of these temporary start states to make it a valid NFA (epsilon-NFA, if you want to nitpick).  Then, we turn it into a DFA as we know we can do.

The only remaining step is to turn our new DFA into a regular expression.  The algorithm for this is stupidly simple: for every path from start to end states, we include that in the regular expression by using `|` (or) for every branch, concatenation for serial states, and `*` (kleene closure) for every loop.

Comment: Hah, I didn't describe how to turn a regular expression into a DFA in the first place.  I'm too drunk to do that now.

Answer (score -1):

You do the negation of the strings that you don't want - e.g.

```
"ten" !~ /one|two|three/
```

This gives you:

```
print "one" !~ /one|two|three/ --> false
print "two" !~ /one|two|three/ --> false
print "ten" !~ /one|two|three/ --> true
```

Comment: This is Perl syntax, but the principle is sound (although apparently, this isn't a viable solution; see the comments in response to my answer).